# postgreSQL: averaging non-null values

Tags: postgresql

Seems simple, but... I have data like so:

```
pid   score1 score2 score3
1     1      3      2
2     3             1
3     4
```

I want to do an average score for the three only where there are non null values. Sort of like `sum(score1+score2+score3)/3` but the denominator essentially needs to be a total of the non-null values for the given row, so 3 for pid `1`, 2 for `2`, and 1 for `3`.

Is there a simple thing I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(pid, score1, score2, score3) as (
    values (1,1,3,2), (2,3,null,1), (3,4,null,null)
)
select
    (sum(score1) + sum(score2) + sum(score3))::numeric / 
    (count(score1) + count(score2) + count(score3))
    as avg,
    avg(coalesce(score1, 0) + coalesce(score2, 0) + coalesce(score3, 0))
    as avg2
from t;
        avg         |        avg2        
--------------------+--------------------
 2.3333333333333333 | 4.6666666666666667
```

Comment: Yeah, that's good. Unfortunately in my work I have 15 columns so it's a big ugly line, but that's the SQL life.

Comment: Yeah, SQL is optimized for column operations, not row operations. I've sometimes found it useful to write throwaway scripts to generate long--but predictable and structured--SQL queries.